# How do you create a function that would take in a list of categories and count the number of elements in each category?

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to return a dictionary the with the categories as keys and the counts as values.

I'm very new to coding but this is what I've come up with so far:

```
def bin_counter(num_list):
    num_dict = {}
    for num in num_list:
        count.num_dict[num] = 'value'
           
    return num_dict
```

Comment: Please provide a set of inputs and the expected output.

Comment: Can you please give an example of the values in `num_list`?

Comment: Could you add an input and the expected output?

Comment: Probably just `return collections.Counter(num_list)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I count the occurrences of a list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, this is the solution:
you can use:

```
collections.Counter(num_list)
```

Or in case you what to understand how to implement the function,the following function will do the job:

```
def bin_counter(num_list):
        num_dict = {}
        for num in num_list:
                try:
                        num_dict[num] += 1
                except KeyError:
                        num_dict[num] = 1
        return num_dict
```

And if you don't familiar with Exeptions, the following function will do the same just without usage of Exeptions:

```
def bin_counter(num_list):
        num_dict = {}
        for num in num_list:
                if num in num_dict:
                        num_dict[num] += 1
                else:
                        num_dict[num] = 1
        return num_dict
```

Comment: This was really helpful, thank you for explaining how I could make a function to do this!

Comment: I happy to help you,

Comment: You can check this answer to let people know you don't need help anymore